# Kendo grid filter change is not selecting the first page so no results are shown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am very new to Kendo Grid and MVC. On my MVC page there is a dropdown which filters data shown in the kendo grid, when i select page 4 when the filter is set to all the grid shows correctly. However when i change the filter(which only has 3 rows) the grid shows no data, the pager is set to 1 but not selected. However when i click the page 1 there is data.

It seems like the pager is stuck at page 4 and not 1 after the filer. Any help is greatly appreciated guys. Thank you!!!

Comment: please share a minimal reproducible example of what you have.

Comment: Set the page to 1 in the script where you filter. `mygrid.query({ page: 1, pageSize: 25 });`